# Debug a Windows Service on a machine without debugger

Tags: windows, debugging, service

I am in the process of creating a Windows service for my application. It all works perfectly on my development machine, but when I try to start it on my test machine (using an installer created with InnoSetup), I get the message that the process suddenly stopped. When looking into some details, I see I get an `ArgumentException`, but now idea where.

I have looked into [debugging Windows services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and that is OK on my development machine, but not for my testmachine.

I could catch the `Exception` in my program, but what to do with it? Is there some way to communicate to a system log, or the `services.msc` program that tries to start it?

Answer (score 0):

I went with the old-fashioned way of debugging: print messages to a file:

```
try {
    ServiceBase.Run(theService);
} catch (Exception e) {
    System.IO.WriteAllText(@"C:\debug.log", e.Message+"; "+e.StackTrace);
}
```